# How to know if a image file is a 360 photo C#

Tags: c#, image

I'm searching how to know in C# if an image is a 360 photo or not, I have read about how to insert 360 metadata in the photo using specific software, but I cannot find how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Many hits on google; you will have to read out the exif data I believe.. [photo.stackexchange.com](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/80520/what-metadata-is-necessary-for-facebook-to-display-a-360%C3%97180-photo-correctly)

Comment: No, this is all related to add metadata to the photo, not to read it by code, but thanks

Comment: Are you sure the images are somehow different? Can you point to an example?

Comment: @TaW is correct - you need to extract the metadata & look for the 360 specific information. There are plenty of websites that explain how to read the metadata & there are plenty of websites that explain what particular metadata needs to be inserted to make the image be recognised as a 360 image. Just combine the knowledge from both.